# Sending mail from a list with smtp

Tags: python, smtplib

I am attempting to send email to a list of recipients using Python, but I am being told to connect first.

```
 import smtplib

    try:

        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.xxx.com', 587)
        s.starttls()

        s.login('barbaramilleraz@xxx.com', 'xxx')
        message = '''

    ...message text...

    '''
        s.connect()
        with open('players.txt') as f:
            email = f.readlines()
            email = [e.strip() for e in email]

            for person in range(len(email)):
                print('Sending email to {}'.format(email[person]))
                s.sendmail('barbaramilleraz', email[person], message)

    except(smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused):
        pass
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\BMiller>python mailing.py
Sending email xxx@xxx.com
Sending email to xxx@xxx.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailing.py", line 25, in <module>
    s.sendmail('barbaramilleraz', email[person], message)
  File "C:\Users\BMiller\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 852, in sendmail
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "C:\Users\BMiller\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 600, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    if not (200 <= self.ehlo()[0] <= 299):
  File "C:\Users\BMiller\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 440, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\BMiller\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 367, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "C:\Users\BMiller\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 359, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

I am new to Python so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: Before being able to do `s.sendmail('barbaramilleraz', email[person], message)` you have to have an open connection with the server (`s.connect()`)

Comment: Thanks. I added the line s.connect() directly above the line s.sendmail(...), but the program only sends one email then exits?

Comment: You explicitly call `s.quit()` after sending each mail. Remove that line and place it after the send loop.

Comment: I moved the s.connect() and deleted s.quit(). Unfortunately, only one email is still being sent.

Answer (score 0):

As dcg says in the comments, you have to call `s.connect()` to establish a connection before sending the email.

You mention it only sends once when you do that: it's because you're calling `s.quit()` after sending each message. Once you've done that, `s` is for all intents and purposes dead: if you want to use it again, you have to start the config all over.

So call `s.connect()` once before sending all messages, and don't call `s.quit()` until you're totally done with `s`.

Comment: Thanks. That was slightly embarrassing. I removed the s.quit(), but the problem remains.Do you think I'm handling the exception correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to skip a recipient when the exception is raised, the exception handling should be around the sendmail call within the loop over the addresses.

```
        for person in range(len(email)):
            print('Sending email to {}'.format(email[person]))
            try:
                s.sendmail('barbaramilleraz', email[person], message)
            except(smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused):
                print('Sender Refused for {}'.format(email[person]))
                continue
```